# What does Lacan mean by signifiers presenting a subject for another signifier?

Tags: linguistics, psychoanalysis, zizek, lacan, freud

I was reading an article on Lacan's Signifier concept posted on nosubject.com. I am very confused by this one sentence:

Lacan defines a signifier as

> "that which represents a subject for another signifier," in opposition to the sign, which "represents something for someone."

Signifiers form an infinite differential chain. s1 -> s2 -> s3 -> ... This chain exists in the domain of the Symbolic, which is outside of the subject / mind, it is in the mysterious Other.

A signifier is an arbitrary and minimal linguistic unit that is only defined by it's difference from all other such units. For example, "cat" is only meaningful because it is not a "bat" or a "hat" etc. I do not understand how can a signifier represent anything, let alone a subject for another signifier.

Can someone clarify this vague Lacanian passage for me?

Link to the post:
https://nosubject.com/Signifier

Comment: Do you have a reference for where in Lacan that passage occurs?

Comment: yes, i updated the question

Answer (score 1):

According to the article you listed, the article differentiates content from utterance, proposition from sentence:

> The signifier is the constitutive unit of the symbolic order because it is integrally related with the concept of structure.

So, what Lacan is on about is the distinction most philosophers make between the content, the semantics, the proposition, the concept, or the message (all variously used) with the utterance, the syntax, the sentence, the encoding, or the medium, resp. Our brains express noises, our minds express ideas. It's fascinating, for instance, that voice recognition as a technology took a long time to improve because look at the structure of a sound wave, words in a sentence aren't broken up physically. They're part of a continuous sound wave. Words, therefore, are a logical imposition on sound constructed by the mind in the same way wavelengths of EM energy in the visual portion of the spectrum aren't actually colors.

Since Charles S. Pierce and Ferdinand de Saussure and the introduction of semiotics, many thinkers have struggled to come to terms with the duality that is inherent in linguistic artifacts. On the one hand, words can be written and spoken, but they seem to depend on a physical medium. No one, for instance, has ever produced scientific evidence of words or ideas transcending physical reality. In philosophy, one might say that ideas supervene on the medium of their expression, and words are no different.

Another model that has a lot of currency is Ogden and Richard's [triangle of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_reference). Lacan glommed onto, according to the article, a different semiotic emphasis:

> Thus for Lacan language is not a system of signs -- as it was for Saussure -- but a system of signifiers.

And that's because he fundamentally disagrees with Saussure:

> Whereas Saussure argues that the signifier and the signified are mutually interdependent, Lacan states that the signifier is primary and produces the signified.

So, whereas this article states Saussure sees the interplay as bidirectional, Lacan takes the signifier as primary. And why?

> It is these meaningless indestructible signifiers which determine the subject; the effects of the signifier on the subject constitute the unconscious, and hence also constitute the whole of the field of psychoanalysis.

So, my interpretation of this statement is that fundamental to the construction of the ego is the use of signifiers. Think about your personal life. How much of your own self-description occurs in language? I suspect nearly all of it. Therefore, psychoanalysis is the art, on this view, of getting a subject or patient to express themselves to give a window into the mind, particularly unconscious mind and the processes associated with. That doesn't seem to controversial by today's standards, the notion that talk therapy provides a window into a patient's mental health, anyway.

In the article:

> The signifier is the constitutive unit of the symbolic order because it is integrally related with the concept of structure.

This is just the [principle of compositionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality) in other words. A word like 'ellucidate' literally decomposes into Latin prefix and stem that means "draw into the light" capturing the extended metaphor of seeing as an analogy to understanding. A passage therefore is understood by the mind processing language and reducing it to signifiers that are primitives, whatever they may be, and why they're interconnected and regress and so on is that words are generally defined in terms of other words. For instance, every word in a dictionary entry for a definition seem to exist as their own entries. Hot relies on cold, up relies on down, temperature relies on measurement, and so on. Thus, we see the typical psychoanalytical approach that there might be great significance in the analysis of a patients words, and that the meanings that you extract from a patient's statements is complex and interconnected:

> Not only can units of language smaller than words (morphemes and phonemes) or larger than words (phrases and sentences) also function as signifiers, but so also can non-linguistic things such as objects, relationships and symptomatic acts.

Thus, morphemes and phonemes comprise lexemes, lexemes comprise phrases and sentences, and those are part of passages which provide context. And to boot, meaning occurs not only with the primitive, but the composition of the parts. Hence, psychoanalysis is part of the movement in philosophy that is recognized as the [linguistic turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_turn). One can administer leeches to cure the brain, or one can have a conversation with someone who is mentally ill and try to construct their perspective (their subjective view, the subject, the phenomenological experience) and find a solution to mental maladies. Believe it or not, this is actually a rather revolutionary view since the history of mental illness often just presumed physical disease or demonic possession or in ancient times, apparently, a wandering uterus in the body. Therefore, Lacan, in the tradition of Freud was advocating an analysis of language to get at the subconscious mind to infer the nature of the impairment so that it might be corrected.

Comment: I don't think signifiers constitute the ego particularly, but rather the "symbolic order" itself, which is very related to "culture" and contrasted with the real and the imaginary orders. In other words, the subject is bathed in signifiers.

Comment: @Frank Is that your view, or your interpretation of his view?

Comment: It seems to be what in the Seminar from Lacan as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Frank You are both right, culture is connected to unconscious. Culture term appeared in 1880 only, before it meaning was about plants growing method. So, culture is a method to forming the unconscious of the Subject. Unconscious is also associated with the sea, and your signified "to have bath"/"bathed" as a signifer of unconscious of Ergo concept - it have place it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sentence is a key:

*i edited for reading more easy: signifies - SS, a signifier - R, a signifiers - Rs, a signified - D...(and this still looks as totally inconsistent)

"It is these meaningless indestructible *signifiers*(Rs) which determine the subject; the effects of the *signifier*(R) on the subject constitute the unconscious, and hence also constitute the whole of the field of psychoanalysis."

But  Saussure said: we have the *signifier*(R) and the *signified*(D) that are *mutually interdependent*.

But Lacan said: "*signifier*(R) without the *signified*(D)"  there is no *signified*(D), only *signifier*(R) (the last one) and I call it the "*pure signifier*(PR)"

Thou must to understand that the subject(S) in Lacan's area is not something that have will power at their actions. S is not decide what to do, but subject has some properties that are influenced on S is doing - S is an actor, but S doesn't control the kind of an action.

Critical mind of S can't open the unconscious knowledges about signs nature, because *signified*(D) is at the blind area. But S can accept signs from *signifier*(R), and in S thoughts this *signifier*(R) can be associate with another *signifier*(R) - thinking process, but when it borrowed till the signified(D)(unconscious area) thinking process stops and S become to action. But the *signified* is a *signifier*(R) for itself that means that it is not a *signified* but the **pure signifier(PR)** with nothing inside.

For example: you are driving and see a sing "arrow to the lef.". You become to think that: arrow means turn to the left and lef. it is the left; turn to the left means: push the steering wheel to "that side". "that side" is signified of left. But you don't think about: why the left is on that side, or what is the "left", or what is "that side". If you don't know what is "the left on that side" you can't turn to the left while driving and same. The left it is the left, it doesn't signifies nothing(more then itself) - "that side" in this subjective action is "a pure *signifier*(SR)". "That side" is a *signifier*(SR) to "...lef.", but "that side" signifies at nothing.

An acoustic image is not same as an image of the thing, maybe it is an image of verb, the acoustic image is an algorithm in the unconscious part of S mind.

And i think that an "acoustic image" can be not only the text, acoustic connected to reflexes system of the brain. Because when you look at something, you have to analyse the things you look at(if it is not picture memes), but when someone call to you that mean that you have to reaction at someone - atleast turn the head to the voice side, and become to listening. Listening it is the unconscious reflex. Remember the commercial advertising: voices or music give mood, bright colors, pictures with food or happy smiling faces - these all can be called "acoustic images". Why this people smiling? You didn't think this was, you think that they smile read they are happy, what means to be happy -  a **"pure signifier(PR)"**.

Also for S the names and self-name especially (that means "I") are usually a **"pure signifier(PR)"**. S can't answer the question "who am i/who art thou" or S answers: I am a baker/the baker...

Answer (score 0):

Take it literally. It quite literally means what it says.

In *The Logic of Phantasy* Seminar 1 (16 Nov. 1966), Lacan states:

> S [the signifier], in so far as it takes the place of the subject, only functions for another signifier.
>
> *Urverdrangung*, or primal repression, is the following: what a signifier >represents for another signifier. It does not bite on
> anything, it constitutes absolutely nothing, it accommodates itself to
> an absolute absence of Dasein.
>
> For around sixteen centuries, at least, the Egyptians hieroglyphs
> remained as solitary as they were uncomprehended in the desert sands,
> it is clear and it has always been clear for everyone that this meant
> that each of the signifiers cut into the stone at least represented a
> subject for the other signifiers. If this was not the way things were
> no one would ever even have taken that to be writing! It is not at all
> necessary that a writing should mean something for anyone whatsoever
> in order for it to be a writing, and in order that, as such, it
> manifests that each sign represents a subject for the one which
> follows it.
>
> If we call that *Urverdrangung*, it means that we are admitting that
> it appears to us to be in conformity with experience, to think about
> what happens - namely, that a subject emerges in the state of barred
> subject - as something which comes from a locus in which it is
> supposedly inscribed, into another locus in which it is going to be
> inscribed anew.

What I understand by that is the subject is equivalent to the Signified (Sd.), the concept to which the Signifier (Sr.) points.

However this subject, this meaning does not have to be actually known or understood by even a single human being for it to function and continue to function indefinitely. Or, nobody need be conscious of the subject for it to exist and carry meaning.

Even for the whole period of time - sixteen centuries - during which nobody understood the meaning of hieroglyphic writing, nor was able to decipher it, the signifiers continued to represent a subject for the other signifiers within that text.

As long as the structure, the inscription, the system of inscription remained unaltered and intact, the signifiers in that text were able to continue representing their subjects but only for the other signifiers. No human being managed to decipher their subject, but that isn't in any way necessary for writing to be writing, all that matters is that the structure remains intact.

And so it is with the system Unconscious. It isn't necessary that anyone should understand it or even be aware of it for the Unconscious to function and be effective. The signifiers of the unconscious by definition don't represent their subjects to us as conscious agents, they represent their subjects to the other signifiers of the unconscious.

But the possibility of deciphering exists. With the right key - psychoanalysis - you can figure out what the Unconscious is trying to say and do.

But also the subject, as the subject of psychoanalysis is that, the place of which is taken by a signifier functioning for another signifier, and moves from the locus in which this signifier is inscribed to another locus in which it is going to be inscribed anew.

Lacan is saying the meaning of the subject is not transparent. In popular discourse it's taken for granted that we know ourselves, more or less, and other people know us, more or less. We are transparent to ourselves and to others. Popular psychology is often about getting to know yourself better, taking a journey within yourself, finding the "real" you, the "authentic" you and so on. But all this from a premise that as subjects we are basically transparent and we are secure in knowing who we are. Moreover, if pushed, you would probably insist that *you* certainly do know yourself, even if other subjects might not know themselves. The illusion of self-knowledge is very convincing after all.

Lacan says that in reality, we don't know anything much about ourselves. The "promotion of consciousness as essential to the subject" in Western philosophy is for Lacan the "deceptive accentuation of the transparency of the I". That comes "at the expense of the opacity of the signifier that undermines the I". The sliding movement, the "*glissement*" of the "*Bewusstsein*" (consciousness) serves to cover up the confusion of the "*Selbst*" (self). [*Subversion of the Subject and the Dialectic of Desire in the Freudian Unconsciousness*]

The real action all happens at the level of the unconscious. The unconscious is constantly dropping hints, through slips of the tongue, jokes, body language, symptoms and dreams of the signs it is representing as signifiers for other signifiers which represent other subjects.

We are constantly communicating unconsciously with others and they with us. Sexual arousal is a classic example. Love at first sight. You might be saying nothing consciously but your body is dropping all kinds of involuntary, unconscious signs of your arousal. You're like a neon sign all lit up without even realizing it. And the object of your arousal might not be aware of anything much consciously either, but if the chemistry is right, you can bet something will happen. There's no need for any conscious awareness at all. Your bodies can take care of everything without any conscious involvement. In this case, your body is a signifier representing the subject for another signifier who is the object of your arousal.